# Application of change of variable to the density of an exponential family?

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

Suppose we have an exponential model that admits a canonical parametrization so that its densities can be written as
$$
l(y;\theta)=C(\theta)\exp\left[\theta^*T(y)+\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\lambda_iS_i(y)\right]\tag{$*$}
$$
where $\theta^*,T(y)\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\theta=(\theta^*,\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_{p-1})'$. Let $S=(S_1,\ldots,S_{p-1})'$.

My text then claims:

> The statistic $(T,S')'$ is sufficient for $\theta$. Thus, we can consider the model induced by this statistic. The probability distributions of the induced model have densities of the form
>   $$
> l(t,s;\theta)=\hat{C}(\theta)\exp\left[\theta^*t+\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\lambda_is_i\right]\tag{$**$}.
> $$

**I understand the claim about sufficiency but where does ($*$$*$) come from?** I thought about using a change of variable formula (assuming that the conditions for its application are satisfied). But there would always be an extra term involving $t,s$ that I didn't know how to get rid of. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If your text really claims $(**)$ in the form you have written it then your text is wrong. Assuming that $T$ is Lipschitz from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, what is true is that
$$
f_T(t,\theta)=g(t)\exp\left[t\theta-K(\theta)\right]
$$
for some measurable function $g$. This follows from the change of variable formula (coarea formula, where $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$ is the $n-1$ dimensional Hausdorff measure and $\mathcal{L}^n$ the Lebesgue measure):
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(T\in A)&=\int_{T^{-1}(A)} \exp\left[T(y)\theta-K(\theta)\right]   \mathcal{L}^n (dy)\\
&=\int_{T(A)} dt \bigg( \int_{T^{-1}(t)} \frac{\exp\left[T(y)\theta-K(\theta)\right]}{|JT|(y)}\mathcal{H}^{n-1}( dy)\bigg)\\
&=\int_{T(A)} dt \, \bigg( \exp\left[t\theta-K(\theta)\right] \int_{T^{-1}(t)} \frac{1}{|JT|(y)}\mathcal{H}^{n-1}( dy)\bigg),
\end{aligned}
$$
and letting $g(t):= \int_{T^{-1}(t)} \frac{1}{|JT|(y)}\mathcal{H}^{n-1}( dy)$.

Since $g$ doesn't depend on $\theta$, the distributions of $T$ as $\theta$ varies in $\Theta$ form an exponential family. So for example $\mathbb{E}(T)=K'(\theta)$ and $Var(T)=K''(\theta)$. More generally, everything is still true if there is an extra term $h(y)$ in the density of $Y$ in $(*)$, i.e. if
$$
f_Y(y;\theta)=h(y)\exp\left[T(y)\theta -K(\theta)\right],
$$
in which case $g(t):= \int_{T^{-1}(t)} h(y) \frac{1}{|JT|(y)}\mathcal{H}^{n-1}( dy)$.